# Relation between ultrafilters ${\scr U}$ and ${\scr U} \otimes {\scr U}$

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters

If ${\scr U}$ and ${\scr V}$ are ultrafilters on non-empty sets $A$ and $B$ respectively, then the *tensor product* ${\scr U}\otimes{\scr V}$ is the following ultrafilter on $A\times B$:
$$\big\{X\subseteq A\times B: \{a\in A:\{b\in B: (a,b)\in X\}\in {\scr V}\}\in {\scr U}\big\}.$$
Is there a non-principal ultrafilter ${\scr U}$ on $\omega$ and a function $f:\omega \to (\omega\times\omega)$ such that $f({\scr U}) = {\scr U}\otimes {\scr U}$?

Comment: No. . . . . . .

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, shouldn't the answer be "yes" because you can just use a projection mapping $\omega \times \omega \rightarrow \omega$ to recover $\mathcal U$ from $\mathcal U \otimes \mathcal U$?

Comment: @WillBrian Projections give you $f(\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U)=\mathcal U$, but the OP is asking for the other direction, $f(\mathcal U)=\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U$, and that is indeed impossible.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks -- I was reading that in the wrong direction.

Comment: The answer on your question is negative as Andreas Blass mentioned. But Katetov proved the existence of filter with property $f(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F}$. See details [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324835/the-example-of-the-idempotent-filter-or-subsets-family-with-finite-intersections).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Will Brian noted in a comment, either projection $p:\omega^2\to\omega$ satisfies $p(\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U)=\mathcal U$. If you also had a function $f$ as in the question, with $f(\mathcal U)=\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U$, then the composite function $f\circ p$ would send $\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U$ to itself. By a result that I quoted at [Selective ultrafilter and bijective mapping](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324254), and for which Ali Enayat supplied a reference, it would follow that $f\circ p$ becomes the identity function when restricted to a suitable set in $\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U$. That is absurd, because $p$ is not one-to-one on any set in $\mathcal U\otimes\mathcal U$.