# ultrapower(ultrapower)=ultrapower

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ultrafilters, ultrapowers

Is there a nonprincipal [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter_(set_theory)) $\omega$ on $\mathbb N$ such that for any metric space $M$ there is an isometry
$$(M^\omega)^\omega\to M^\omega?$$
(In other words, the [$\omega$-power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of $\omega$-power of $M$ is isometric to the $\omega$-power of $M$.)

**Comments.**

- You may assume that $M$ has finite diameter, otherwise $M^\omega$ is an $\infty$-metric space; that is, distance between points might take infinite value.
- I want to thank [Will Brian](https://mathoverflow.net/users/70618/will-brian) for pointing to [this post of Andreas Blass](https://mathoverflow.net/a/324261/). It solves my problem negatively, at least if one assumes some natural condition on the isometry.

Comment: I presume $M^\omega$ is the "standard part" of the usually-defined ultrapower, right (namely, take the subset of the full ultrapower consisting of points a finite distance from the image of some element of $M$, and then quotient out by the infinitesimal distance relation)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I added a comment about it.

Comment: You still need to mod out by infinitesimal distance - otherwise, it's not a genuine metric space. For example, consider (the points corresponding to) the constant sequence $(0,0,0,...)$ and the harmonic sequence $(1,{1\over 2},{1\over 3},{1\over 4},...)$ in the ultrapower of $[0,1]$ (with the usual metric).

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I think this thread is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324254/selective-ultrafilter-and-bijective-mapping. If I understand correctly, Andreas' answer there blocks a plausible way to proving a positive answer to your question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ultralimit is usually defined as the corresponding metric space to the constructed pseudometric space; that is, it is a metric on equivalence classes defined by $x\sim y$ iff $|x-y|=0$.

Comment: Is this possible for arbitrary first-order structures (in a countable language)? You can code arbitrary first-order structures in metric spaces in a way that is compatible with ultraproducts.